# Problem with unmarshaling xsd:base64Binary

Tags: xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

JAXB generated from XSD base64Binary and hexBinary to byte array. I have xsd element with base64Binary. This is strict and cannot be changed. But in this element we has value of hexBinary (yea a little bit confused). And now where it is problem. I dont dont how is JAXB unmarshaling these element but there is something not sutaible to me. So if there could be hexBinary  in my element it unmarshaling right. But im my case element has type base64Binary and JAXB unmarshaling these element something else what is wrong to me. Is there a way to change how JAXB handle with these element and tell him to handle as these element would be hexBinary.
maybe confusing question but I need help with these.

so in shortly way I have element base64Binary  but I wanna to tell JAXB to unmarshaling as these will be hexBinary

I read something that I have to create new XmlAdapter but I dont know where should I use it because I have just classes which generated JAXB

UPDATE:

I found where is a problem. when element is base64Binary  in generated class it created this

```
XmlElement(name="name") protected byte[] element
```

but when it is hexBinary it create

```
XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class) XmlElement(name="name") protected byte[] element
```

so now I need to know how to say jaxb to use these adapter when I have base64Binary
protected byte[] element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You should be able to do what you want using a JAXB schema bindings file like the following:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="YourSchema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='element']">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType name="byte[]"
                        parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary" 
                        printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary"/>
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

---

There are a couple of options:

**Option #1 - `@XmlSchemaType`**

You can use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to control the schema representation;

```
@XmlSchemaType(name="hexBinary")
private byte[] hexBinary;

@XmlSchemaType(name="base64Binary")
private byte[] base64Binary;
```

**Option #2 - `XmlAdapter`**

If you want to generate your model from an XML schema and leverage an XmlAdapter instead, the following example demonstrates how it could be done:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Comment: yea but how can I set this in generated class ?

Comment: @hudi - Am I correct that you have base64Binary in the XML schema, but the corresponding XML element represent hexBinary data?

Comment: @hudi - You could apply a style sheet on the schema to produce a copy with the correct type.  Or you could you try the second option and generate an `XmlAdapter`.

Comment: hm xml adapter is already created in jaxb. is there easily way to add just these notation ?

Comment: I try your tutorial but I dont understand the part ROOT. you are changing code which was generated by JAXB ? if I generated it again it will be rewrited or ?

Comment: @hudi - In the example I am not changing generated code, I just posted what was generated.  The only thing that is hand coded in my example is the `NumberFormatter` class.

Comment: oh ok so NumberFormatter created xmlAdapter. but I wanna use xmlhexadapter which is just created in jaxb so is there a easily way to use it ?

Comment: @hudi - I have updated my answer to leverage the built-in javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter class.  This should give you what you are looking for.